# How to trace/track/profile/capture/break "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"?

Tags: go, delve

is there a magic to identify where these mystery `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference messages come from?`

[image]

I tried setting breakpoint everywhere but no luck. It's not from any of my loggings - probably from some 3rd party library.

I also tried `log.SetFlags(LstdFlags|Llongfile)` but doesn't change any verbosity.

I remember in some other languages + debugger there is always a way to find out when segmentation fault or null pointer reference exception takes place. Is there such magic for Golang?

Thanks!

Comment: Delve *has* a default break on fatal panics, so something weird is going on.

Comment: If you can catch the panic with a recover and print the stack, you can pinpoint where it is happening.

Answer (score 2):

See [defer, panic and recover](https://go.dev/blog/defer-panic-and-recover) on the go blog.

When running a deferred function, if the defer is executed in reaction to a panic, the stack still contains the state at panic time :

```golang
func withTrace() {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Printf("caught panic: %s\n", r)
            var stack [4096]byte
            n := runtime.Stack(stack[:], false)
            fmt.Printf("%s", stack[:n])
            fmt.Println("\n// notice how 'trigger()' appears in the stack trace above,\n// even though the 'defer' is called from 'withTrace()'")
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("=== running withTrace() ...")
    trigger()
}

// Output:
=== running withTrace() ...
caught panic: from trigger
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.withTrace.func1()
    /tmp/sandbox2519976531/prog.go:31 +0x8b
panic({0x48a120, 0x4b8c60})
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/panic.go:884 +0x212
main.trigger(...)
    /tmp/sandbox2519976531/prog.go:11
main.withTrace()
    /tmp/sandbox2519976531/prog.go:38 +0x8c
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox2519976531/prog.go:43 +0x1c

// notice how 'trigger()' appears in the stack trace above,
// even though the 'defer' is called from 'withTrace()'
```

https://go.dev/play/p/MOapLmcSVVt

---

You would have to place this call to `recover()` somewhere in the sequence of functions that execute your handlers.

In an http server, if you want to trace every possible panic in your handlers, a good place is a middleware set on all routes.